# Algebra partial derivative using chain rule for $f (x, y, z) =\frac{\sin z}{x^2+y^2}$.

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

Hi i am trying to solve this question

$$f (x, y, z) =\dfrac{\sin z}{x^2+y^2}$$

where 
$$x (r, θ, h) = r \cos θ$$
$$y (r, θ, h) = r \sin θ$$
$$z (r, θ, h) = h$$

first part of the question was to express the function in the cylindrical coordinates which i did and the you had to find the partial derivatives i was able to do that but how do you calculate the partial derivatives using the chain rule ?

Comment: Use
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} =  \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial r} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial r}   + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial r}$$

Comment: thanks for the reply

Comment: just to make sure if i am doing the right way  i got for df/dr=(-2x*sin(z)*cos(u)/(x^2+y^2)^2+(-2*y*sin(z)*sin(u))/(x^2+y^2)^2+(cos(z))/(x^2+y^2)

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial r}=$?